# Is there a shortcut to stop outlining in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

Is there a shortcut to stop outlining in Visual Studio?

Do I need to use resharper to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

You can bind a key to Edit.StopOutlining in the Options dialog (Environment | Keyboard).

It's set on [Ctrl+M, P] by default, at least on my system.

Answer (score 1):

HotKey is CTRL+M,P. And you can find all outlining functions in Edit - Outlining

Answer (score 0):

also, you can right click in an editor and choose it from the context menu